# Which function satisfies this integral condition?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is it possible to find a class of functions $F(x, y):\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that there exists a function $G:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ such that the following condition is satisfied
\begin{align}
\int_{-y_2}^{y_1}F(x, y)ydy=G(y_1)-G(y_2), \quad\forall y_1, y_2\in\mathbb R.
\end{align}
One possibility is to take $F(x, y)=f(y)$ $\forall x\in\mathbb Rn$ with $f(y)=f(-y)$ because in that case I could choose $G(a):=\int_0^af(y)ydy$. There exists another class of functions?

Comment: Something does not quite add up there. In your case $y$ is a one-dimensional variable, but the limits of your integral are $n$-dimensional.

Comment: You are right... I modified the text! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Okay. One thing you get is that
$$
\int_{-a}^a Fy\,dy = G(a)-G(a) = 0
$$
This implies that for any positive measurable set $A$ we need to have
$$ \int_A Fy\,dy + \int_{-A} Fy\,dy = 0$$
But this implies that $F(x,y)=F(x,-y)$ almost everywhere (else you could consider the set of all $y>0$ so that $F(x,y)>F(x,-y)$ or the set where $F(x,y)<F(x,-y)$ and thus find a set of positive mass so that the above does not hold).

(Also this implies symmetry of $G$, as $\int_a^b \ldots = \int_{-a}^b\ldots$ we have $G(b)-G(-a)=G(b)-G(a)$).

The other condition we need to care about is that for any Interval $[a,b]$ the integral
$$ \int_a^b F(x,y)y\, dy=G(b)-G(-a)$$
does not depend on $x$. Note that this does also imply that the integral over arbitrary measurable sets $A$ does not depend on $x$. But this implies that $F(x_1,y)=F(x_2,y)$ for almost all $y$. Else we could define $A$ to contain all points $y$ so that $F(x_1,y)<F(x_2,y)$ or the other way round. If one of these sets had positive mass the integrals would depend on $x$.

So the conditions on $F$ we get are:

- $F(x,y)=F(x,-y)$ for almost all $y$
- $F$ does not depend on $x$, so $F(x_1,y)=F(x_2,y)$ for all $x_1,x_2$ for almost all $y$.

The almost everywhere conditions might of course depend on $x$.